# Golang template can't access file in embedFS

Tags: go, embed, go-templates

my golang code arch is as bellow:

```
├── embeded.go
├── go.mod
├── json
│   └── file
└── main.go
```

and this is my embede.go code:

```golang
package main

import "embed"

//go:embed json/*
var templatesFS embed.FS

func TemplatesFS() embed.FS {
    return templatesFS
}
```

now in my main.go I can't access file in json directory:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "os"
    "text/template"
)

func main() {
    tmpl := template.Must(
        template.New("json/file").
            ParseFS(TemplatesFS(), "json/file"))
    if err := tmpl.Execute(os.Stdout, "config"); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}
```

when I run above code I got error `template: json/file: "json/file" is an incomplete or empty template`

but I can access the `file` like this:

```
file, err := TemplatesFS().ReadFile("json/file")
```

so why I can't access it in templte.execute ?

How Can I Solve It ?

Comment: why don't you use `//go:embed json/file` in embeded.go ?

Comment: @MeMe because I want to access to all files in that directory with one line of code. I don't want to repeat code for each file in that directory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The template parser successfully read a template from the embedded file system.

The Execute method reports that the template `tmpl` is incomplete.  The variable `tmpl` is set to the template created by the call to New. The template is incomplete because the application did not parse a template with the template's name, `json/file`.

ParseFS names templates using the file's base name. Fix by using using the file's base name in the call to New.

```
tmpl := template.Must(
    template.New("file").ParseFS(TemplatesFS(), "json/file"))
```